# Setting graphical environment: dpkg-reconfigure or update-alternatives?

Tags: debian, desktop-environment

I'm confused about setting correct programs. For example, what determines that `lightdm` is my current display manager? Why is there no debian alternative for it?

```
x-session-manager              manual   /usr/bin/startxfce4
x-terminal-emulator            manual   /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper
x-window-manager               manual   /usr/bin/xfwm4
```