# `update-alternatives` vs `dpkg-reconfigure`

Tags: debian, ubuntu, package-management, dpkg, alternatives

From [Why is the default shell on my Ubuntu 14.04 bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/292599/674):

> On Debian derivatives, you can switch between Dash and Bash as the default `/bin/sh` by running `dpkg-reconfigure` dash as root.

Is it correct that both `update-alternatives` and `dpkg-reconfigure` can be used for changing the executable which a symlink in `/bin/` links to?

If yes, for this purpose, what are the differences between `update-alternatives` and `dpkg-reconfigure`?

Thanks.

Comment: Prior questions include https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408598/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418852/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418985/ .

Answer (score 5):

`update-alternatives` can indeed be used to manage symlinks under `/bin`, or even anywhere else; [that’s its purpose](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/418852/86440). It requires cooperating packages, or manual setup — the various alternatives need to be registered.

`dpkg-reconfigure` isn’t specific at all, it only runs a package’s post-installation maintainer script. So its behaviour is entirely dependent on the specific package it’s used to configure. In `bash` and `dash`’s case, the maintainer scripts handle the `/bin/sh` symlink, so yes, in this particular case `dpkg-reconfigure` is used to manage a symlink.

The reason why `bash` and `dash` don’t use `update-alternatives` to manage the `/bin/sh` is simply that when the possibility was enabled, `update-alternatives` wasn’t considered robust enough to be relied upon for such a sensitive file as `/bin/sh`. If *anything* ever goes wrong and `/bin/sh` ends up either removed, or pointing at a non-existent file, the system is rendered largely useless and hard to fix; it won’t even boot properly... So `bash` and `dash` take great care to ensure that `/bin/sh` is always usable. This involves some careful processing in their pre-installation “script” (which is actually a binary, to avoid pre-dependency loops), a trick involving `dpkg-divert`, and some last-ditch handling in their post-installation scripts. You’ll find details of the design of all this in [bug #34717](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=34717) (nineteen years ago).

To tell which binaries in a system are handled using alternatives, and which are handled using diversions (from maintainer scripts), you can use the corresponding tools, in particular `dpkg-divert --list` which will list all diversions. For `update-alternatives --list` you need to know the alternative group you’re interested in, but alternatives are easy to spot because they’re all symlinks to a file in `/etc/alternatives`.

Answer (score 2):

The `update-alternatives` command requires that all alternatives register to it, in order for it to manage which alternative will get the symlink in /bin pointing to.

The alternatives system is quite flexible, as it can manage multiple symlinks at once and can handle multiple alternative implementations, possibly giving them weights that will help decide which one will be selected when more than two are installed, and will also gracefully pick the one that has the next highest weight if that one gets uninstalled.

The scheme used by `dpkg-reconfigure dash` uses dpkg's diversion system, where one package (bash) ships `/bin/sh`, but then other packages can "divert" that to override with their implementations.

dpkg's diversion system is not limited to symlinks (can also divert files) and doesn't require the main package to ship the original symlink (or file) to be modified to adopt a system such as `update-alternatives`.

The diversion system is not as flexible as the alternatives system, as it usually depends on packages to configure to put themselves to the top of the diversion and in many cases doesn't do any configuration at all (just installing a new package automatically diverts files from a previosly installed package, with no configuration.) These limitations also make it harder to use dpkg's diversion system to implement more than two alternatives.

Comment: Thanks. Could you show how to change what shell is installed at `/bin/sh` by using `update-alternatives` and by using `dpkg-reconfigure` respectively?

Comment: Well, you can't change `/bin/sh` using `update-alternatives` unless your distribution decided to manage it using the alternatives system, which is not the case... They are using the dpkg diversion system to manage that. So, in short, there's no good way to do that using `update-alternatives`.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04, some symlinks under `/user/bin/` are managed by `update-alternatives`. How can you tell what symlinks are managed by `update-alternatives`, and what by `dpkg-reconfigure`?  How do you know `/bin/sh` is by `dpkg-reconfigure` not by `update-alternatives` in particular?